# Low-level Keyhook

Tags: c#, keyhook

I would like to run a low-level keyhook on a seperate thread in C# to detect for certain hotkeys. How would I do this?

Comment: There are many questions and answers on this topic here on SO. A very complete example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-whkeyboardll-in-wpf-c Suggest you search on "GetAsyncKeyState" as well as "global hook," "keyboard hook," "lower-level keyboard hook," etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this keyboard hook only to detect hot keys then you should not use a hook.  Windows supports hot keys with the RegisterHotKey() API function.  Check my code sample in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/2622427d-1e15-4f30-b01d-57b0ba054f5c) to see how to use it.  There's a C# sample further down the page.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this library :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can to use DirectX.
Add a reference to Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput (after you've installed directX on your machine. [Here is the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=b66e14b8-8505-4b17-bf80-edb2df5abad4&displaylang=en).)

Create an instance of the device class:

```
keyboard = new Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.Device(SystemGuid.Keyboard);
```

And you can now listen to the keyboard.