# MenuStrip requiring double click when

Tags: c#, winforms

**My Win Forms application:**

My WinForms application has two forms.
Form1 has a button which opens Form2 and both forms have their own separate MenuStrip.

**Reproduction Scenario:**

The Form starts and everything works.
The MenuStrip displays its underlying MenuStripItems on one click.
When opening the second Form, everything on that form also works with one click.
After closing the second form and clicking on the MenuStrip of the first form, nothing happens. 
A second click is required to open the MenuStrip. 
Also, when opening the second form, the following click on the MenuStrip does not do anything.
Again a second click is required to open the MenuStrip.
Note that the second form is constructed each time it is displayed.

So far I have tried:

- Setting the focus (using Focus() and Activate()) to the MenuStrip as soon as the second form closes (didn't work)
- Creating my own MenuStrip and overloading WndProc, OnClick, OnVisible, etc. to set the focus (didn't work) and to simulate a second OnClick (didn't work).

I also don't think it is focus related, as problem remains when the Focused property is on true before the click.

Another aspect to this problem is, that when I run my application on Windows 7/8, it seems to work perfectly.
When running the app on Windows Server 2008 R2, the MenuStrips always require a double click the second time the Form is shown.
Both machines use .NET framework 4.5

Comment: possible duplicate of [window not catching first event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321086/window-not-catching-first-event)

Comment: The focus issue seems to be unrelated (which I also explained). I've tried the solution as described, but that didn't work. Also, this behavior is identical on Windows 7/8 (as it is standard Windows behavior) and my problem does not occur on Windows 7/8.