# KeyBinding without a command in WPF

Tags: wpf, key-bindings

I've a simple WPF app, and I'd like to add what is known in the Win32 world as keyboard accelerators. It looks like KeyBinding is the ticket, but it requires binding to a Command object. I'm not using command objects, nor do I want to. Is there another way to get an event triggered when a ctrl-x key sequence is hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should be looking into hooks.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

[Using global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) in WPF / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp)

HTH

Comment: So, the easier way appears to be just to give in and use command objects. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that I can think of why anyone would ***not*** want to use command objects is if they have them in their mind associated with the viewmodel, while they want their keybinding to work exclusively within the view.

And indeed, if you try to declare an `ICommand` in the view, it is surprisingly hard to manage to bind the `KeyBinding` to it.

This is how I solved this problem in my project:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView"
    (...)
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
    (...)
    <Grid>
        <Grid.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="R" Command="{Binding ReportCommand, 
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyView}}" />
    (...)
```

`ReportCommand` is an `ICommand` in `MyView`, not in the ViewModel.