# Is there a way to make copying and pasting HTML to contenteditable consistent in major modern browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

For example, when I'm pasting whole Stackoverflow page to conteneditable in Chrome, it preserves most of its formatting. When I do the same in Firefox part of the data (styles) is lost. The same is true for IE.

Probably, it depends on the different internal handling of Copy&Paste mechanism in different browsers and we cannot do anything about it. 
Nevertheless, maybe there is some clever hack around it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please see [Browser Support and Issues for Clipboard API](http://caniuse.com/#search=clipboard), Also read the question and answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470272/how-to-paste-on-click-it-works-in-google-docs/34473542#34473542 it has full answer)it has full answer

Comment: I am sorry, but that answer has nothing to do with my question. I am interested in **preserving** formatting (e.g.. Html) of data that has been copied. As far as I understand, Copy in different browsers works in different ways regarding content. (Chrome copies data one way, Firefox another(tried to paste HTML copied by Chrome in Firefox, and, it worked as expected). Anyways, I think it is not possible (no data on the web about it). So the question is, mostly, if somebody could have some interesting suggestions regarding the problem.

Comment: Actually I posted the two links to know limitations and different browsers support and issues, for simple regular text copy/paste, mind rich formatted data which you're trying to be able to paste it, IMHO I don't think it could be avalailablel and cross-browser soon

Comment: Anyways, I resort to _only chrome_ app then. Thanks.