# Make Google Docs' clipboard work when embedded in an Electron webview

Tags: javascript, google-docs, electron

I'm embedding a Google Docs webapp in a `webview` in an Electron app.

The keyboard copy-paste (Cmd+C/Cmd+V on mac) works perfectly but the web clipboard, the one triggered via menus (**Edit > Copy**) does not work:
[image]

Does anyone know how to make it work in Electron?

Note that I can reproduce the issue with the [Brave](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop) browser, browser based on Electron. Note also that Safari displays the [same kind of notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8CGh.png).

I read [there](http://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2014/04/13/copy-and-paste-in-google-docs/7568661/) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470272/how-to-paste-on-click-it-works-in-google-docs) that Chromes implements some kind of exception with the [Clipboard API](https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/) for the google apps to make it works. I'd be interested to implement the same kind of exception with Electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this piece of code in `webview`'s `preload` and the message disappears and clipboard works as expected:

```
(function () {
  window._docs_chrome_extension_exists = !0;
  window._docs_chrome_extension_features_version = 1;
  window._docs_chrome_extension_permissions = ["alarms", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "storage", "unlimitedStorage"];
})()
```

Indeed, by looking closely at what the [Google Drive extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-docs-offline/ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi) is doing, I realized that the extension is loading this piece of code in every tab matching Google Drive's URLs.