# Javascript: on click get and assign values on clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I have this line of code that works when I'm using the paste event:

```
//This works
document.addEventListener('paste', e => {
  console.log("e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');", 
               e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

But I need to copy and paste with a button so:

```
//Not Working
jQuery(buttonId).click(e => {
  console.log("e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');", 
               e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470272/how-to-paste-on-click-it-works-in-google-docs

Comment: would also suggest you think about using a library that has implemented the clipboard API with fallbacks and everything that is required to avoid pitfalls.. https://clipboardjs.com/

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
   $("#buttonId").on("click",e => {
   console.log("e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');", 
               e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
   });
```

> $ symbol is used instead of jQuery keyword
>      , '#' is id selector in jQuery