# Porting Chrome extension to Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

I have created a chrome extension to enable clipboard data access. The solution is explained in details here [Implementing 'Paste' in custom context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178302/implementing-paste-in-custom-context-menu/48342112#48342112). Now the problem is how to port this extension to Edge. There is a tool for that I know I used it, and maybe it is working, but my problem is how to "consume" this extension, what is equivalent to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in Edge? In Chrome I used this https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage - the part 'Sending messages from webpages', but in Edge I just can't find anything similar. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. There is no way (at least I couldn't find it) to communicate from web page with extension background script (and only the background script can get data from the clipboard and has the 'browser' object defined). So what I did, I communicated with content script and content script communicated with background script. Here is the code.

PAGE CODE:

```
contextMenuPaste: function () {
    if (getBrowserName() == 'EDGE') {
         window.postMessage({
            direction: "from-page-script"
         }, "*");
    }
},

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    if (event.source == window &&
        event.data.direction &&
        event.data.direction == "from-content-script") {
        console.log('Data in page script', event.data.message);
    }
});
```

CONTENT SCRIPT CODE

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  // If message came from page-script send request to background script to get clipboard data
  if (event.source == window &&
    event.data &&
    event.data.direction == "from-page-script") {
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({
        message: "getClipboardData"
      },
      function(clipboardData) {
        messagePageScript(clipboardData);
      }
    );
  }
});

// Send clipboard data to page script
function messagePageScript(clipboardData) {
  window.postMessage({
    direction: "from-content-script",
    message: clipboardData
  }, "*");
}
```

BACKGROUND SCRIPT CODE

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(req, sender, callback) {
    if (req) {
      if (req.message) {
         if (req.message == "installed") {
           console.log('Checking is extension is installed!');
           callback(true);
         }
         else if(req.message = "getClipboardData") {
           console.log('Get clipboard data');
           callback(getDataFromClipboard());
         }
       }
    }
    return true;
  }
);

function getDataFromClipboard() {
  var bg = browser.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  var helperTextArea = bg.document.getElementById('sandbox');
  if (helperTextArea == null) {
    helperTextArea = bg.document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(helperTextArea);
  }
  helperTextArea.value = '';
  helperTextArea.select();

  // Clipboard data
  var clipboardData = '';

  bg.document.execCommand("Paste");
  clipboardData = helperTextArea.value;
  helperTextArea.value = '';

  return clipboardData;
}
```

But there is one tiny issue. This code works if I have a break-point set on line

```
bg.document.execCommand("Paste");
```

and it doesn't if I don't have that break-point. I thought it is a trimming issue, added pauses, delayed executions but nothing helped. I will start a new question for that issues and will copy solution here (if I find one).

Answer (score 1):

There is `runtime.sendMessage()` in Edge too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage

The thing to keep in mind is that the `runtime` object is defined on the `browser` object, not `chrome`.

> Sends a single message to event listeners within your extension or a different extension.
>
> If sending to your extension, omit the extensionId argument. The runtime.onMessage event will be fired in each page in your extension, except for the frame that called runtime.sendMessage.
>
> If sending to a different extension, include the extensionId argument set to the other extension's ID. runtime.onMessageExternal will be fired in the other extension.
>
> Extensions cannot send messages to content scripts using this method. To send messages to content scripts, use tabs.sendMessage.
>
> This is an asynchronous function that returns a Promise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed chrome.runtime.sendMessage with browser.runtime.sendMessage in my web application - the one that is 'calling' the extension for clipboard data. And I get this error SCRIPT5009: 'browser' is not defined.