# How to detect the ctrl key is pressed twice if the program is minimized or in system tray

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, c#-4.0, winforms-interop

How to detect the ctrl key is pressed twice if the program is minimized or in system tray

I am trying to develop a c# program where the main form will be shown to the user when the control key is pressed twice. I found samples for hotkey combinations but this is not hotkey with combination, like control+ some other key. This is like google desktop app where the search box is displayed when control key is pressed twice.

Comment: [Processing Global Mouse & Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) in WPF / C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyboard hooking as suggested. It's been nicely wrapped for you at [CodePlex](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/), where you get a .NET API simply raising Key and Mouse events, regardless of the state your app is in.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a case of [keyboard hooking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (`WH_KEYBOARD`).

Comment: You will have to use `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` if you want to write the hook in C#. The low-level mouse and keyboard hooks are the only ones that don't require DLL injection, which isn't possible using a managed language. If you want to use `WH_KEYBOARD`, you must write a DLL in C or C++, and then call that from your C# app.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is capture each time the key is pressed, and perhaps in a background worker compare the difference in time.

Set yourself a threshold and if it is less than that, you would consider it a double press and do what you need to.

Untested the components could look something like:

```
    private readonly DateTime _originDateTime = new DateTime(0);
    private DateTime _lastKeyPress;
```

Hook up worker:

```
        _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerSupportsCancellation = false };
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoBackgroundWork;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Implement DoBackgroundWork method:

```
    private void DoBackgroundWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
    {
        do
        { 
                if (_lastKeyPress != _originDateTime)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(DelayInMilliseconds);
                    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                    TimeSpan delta = now - _lastKeyPress;

                    if (delta < new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, DelayInMilliseconds))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                //do stuff

        } while (true);
    }
```

And don't forget to capture the key:

```
    private void SomeEvent_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

This is based on [XPath Visualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/42182#533256)

Answer (score 1):

Use keyboard hooks like foxx1337 suggested, then do something like this:

```
int triggerThreshold = 500; //This would be equivalent to .5 seconds
int lastCtrlTick = 0;

private void OnCtrlPress()
{
    int thisCtrlTick = Environment.TickCount;
    int elapsed = thisCtrlTick - lastCtrlTick;
    if (elapsed <= triggerThreshold)
    {
        LaunchYourAppOrWhatever();
    }
    lastCtrlTick = thisCtrlTick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
The managed wrapper .NET library library mentioned in an accepted answer has moved [here](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook). Now there is also a [nuget package MouseKeyHook](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=MouseKeyHook) available.

Recently support for detecting shortcuts, key combinations and sequences was added. Here is a usage example:

```
void DoSomething()
{
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed UNDO");
}

Hook.GlobalEvents().OnCombination(new Dictionary<Combination, Action>
{
    {Combination.FromString("Control+Z"), DoSomething},
    {Combination.FromString("Shift+Alt+Enter"), () => { Console.WriteLine("You Pressed FULL SCREEN"); }}
});
```

For more information see: [Detecting Key Combinations and Seuqnces](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook/blob/vNext/keycomb.md)