# Why are KeyUp and KeyDown events getting slower?

Tags: wpf, keyboard-events

I am using the `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events on a WPF Window.

I also have a lot of calls in the CompositionTarget_Rendering event of this window that creates UIElements and animate them. This is done by the engine class below:

```
int _Fps;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

void CompositionTarget_Rendering_Stats(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _Fps++;
    var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    sw.Restart();
    engine.Update(ms / 1000f);
    timeFrames.Add(ms);
}
```

I have noticed that the more of elements I have, the slower get `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` events.

When I have around 1000 UIelements in the main Window, **the code of both control_KeyDown and control_KeyUp is executed around half a second after I hit or released a key**.

This would not surprise me if the animations inside the Window were laggy too, but it is not the case.

- The framerate is at around 55 fps
- The animation remains smooth
- The calculations in the `CompositionTarget_Rendering` event does not last more than 20 milliseconds.

It seems that only the keyboard event polling is suffering from heavy conditions.

My question are:

- What is the magic behind Keyboard handling in WPF: why is it getting laggy under heavy condition while not the rendering process?
- How can I handle better keyboards input and avoid this ?

**EDIT:**

I wrote a sample inspired by Andy comment. You can copy paste it in the main Windows of a fresh WPF application. It changes the color of the window as a key is down or up, and it fills as many textboxes as possible in the CompositionTarget_Rendering event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    WrapPanel root2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        root2 = new WrapPanel();
        root2.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        this.Content = root2;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            root2.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Background = Brushes.Yellow });

        this.KeyDown += MainWindow_KeyDown;
        this.KeyUp += MainWindow_KeyUp;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
    }

    void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }

    void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Green;
    }

    void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var child in root2.Children)
            ((TextBlock)child).Text = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
    }
}
```

Depending on your machine performances, change the 2000 to increase the number of textboxes. At a certain amount, there is more CompositionTarget_Rendering triggers than KeyUp or KeyDown. It is quite visible when a key is pressed to see the color change of the border: the key is down, then the Composition_Rendering is triggered several time, then the keydown event is triggered and the border turns to red.

Comment: If I setup a new project, create a new form and add a loop to create 50,000 textboxes and hook the main windows KeyDown event, I actually don't notice any delay at all. Are these nested controls?

Comment: No controls are nested. Would you like please to try to put some code inside the CompositionTarget_Rendering event to put some random text inside the TextBox? I think it will reflect the conditions I have. 50000 textboxes is a lot, thought.

Comment: Wonder if putting the TextBoxes in a virtualizing container like a ListBox would help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think it is related to something I dont know like priorities in events or whatever.

Comment: On my machine, the process gets heavy cpu usage, no wonder that everything is delayed. i.e. not the key-events get delayed, everything on that machine will get slower

Comment: That's true. Now I realize the sample is probably too UI intensive compared to my situation where the keys events are slow to respond although both CPU and framerate are good. I will add a better sample code as soon time allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To respond to my second question, I have found an alternate way to do a **global keyboard hook**: [Using global keyboard hook (WH_KEYBOARD_LL) in WPF / C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Its `Keyup` and `Keydown` events responds without lag, event under heavy CPU and graphic load.