# Get long combination key (password) entered in WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

I'm having a bit of confusion regarding my post here. How to get combination key about 5-10 keys? I'm intended to capture "!qaz$esz" key without double quotes.

My application is a full screen application that prevent access to desktop before entering a right key to enable desktop access. I have kill explorer.exe and disable the Task Manager when the program start and enable it back after combination password is correct:-

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /** 
         * 1.   KILL EXPLORER
         * 2.   DISABLE KEY TO TERMINATE
         *      = Alt + F4
         *      = Win + Tab
         *      = Win + D
         *      = etc
         * 3.   ACCEPT SPECIFIC KEY ONLY TO UNLOCK TO MINIMIZE AND SET TOP = FALSE
         * 
         * 
         * **/
        RegistryKey regkey = SetKey(TaskManager.Disabled);
        regkey.Close();
    }
    public static RegistryKey SetKey(TaskManager command)
    {
        RegistryKey mKey;
        string subKey = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
        mKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey);
        switch (command)
        {
            case TaskManager.Enabled:
                mKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 0);
                break;
            case TaskManager.Disabled:
                mKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", 1);
                break;
        }
        return mKey;
    }
```

But something must be lack on my code where I cannot detect the combination code that more to password.

Below code are what I'm testing to see if my entered key is captured.

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AddHandler(Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, (KeyEventHandler)HandleKeyDownEvent);
    }
    private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift)) == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL + SHIFT + TAB trapped"); // Working
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Tab && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CTRL + TAB trapped"); // Working
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.F4 && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ALT + F4 trapped"); // Not working
        }
        if (e.Key == Key.D && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Windows))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("WIN + D trapped"); // Not working
        }
        if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && e.Key == Key.D1) && e.Key ==Key.Q && e.Key == Key.A && e.Key == Key.Z && e.Key == Key.D4 && e.Key == Key.E && e.Key == Key.S && e.Key == Key.Z)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("COMBOKEY"); // Not working
            // RUN EXPLORER
            // ENABLE TASK MANAGER
        }
    }
```

What is not settle is <kbd>WINLOGO + D</kbd>, <kbd>ALT + TAB</kbd>, <kbd>ALT + F4</kbd> and LONG COMBINATION KEY.

I have try some of the code from here:-

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750757/3436326
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17088823/3436326

I have see some discussion/posting/article on writing to LowLevelAPI. I'm not familiar accessing low level API and apply it on WPF application:-

1. http://www.tamas.io/c-disable-ctrl-alt-del-alt-tab-alt-f4-start-menu-and-so-on/
2. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14485/low-level-windows-api-hooks-from-c-to-stop-unwante

Comment: your combo key wont work because you simply cant press all those keys at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.Key == Key.Q && e.Key == Key.A
```

If `e.Key` is equal to `Key.Q`, it **cannot** be equal to `Key.A` at the same time. That’s why it’s not working. What you want to detect is the *sequence* of those keys, and since you only have a key listener, you have to take care of managing the state yourself:

```
private int passwordState = 0;

private void HandleKeyDownEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // other checks

    else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && e.Key == Key.D1)
        passwordState = 1; // first key of the password
    else if (passwordState == 1 && e.Key == Key.Q)
        passwordState = 2;
    else if (passwordState == 2 && e.Key == Key.A)
        passwordState = 3;
    else if (passwordState == 3 && e.Key == Key.Z)
        passwordState = 4;
    else if (passwordState == 4 && e.Key == Key.D4)
        passwordState = 5;
    else if (passwordState == 5 && e.Key == Key.E)
        passwordState = 6;
    else if (passwordState == 6 && e.Key == Key.S)
        passwordState = 7;
    else if (passwordState == 7 && e.Key == Key.Z)
    {
        passwordState = 0;

        // correct password
        MessageBox.Show("COMBOKEY");
    }
    else
        passwordState = 0; // some other/unexpected key: reset password state
}
```

But that is really annoying to maintain, so why don’t you have a special key combination instead that simply shows a modal prompt for the user to enter the password? Yes, you would show the user a clear password prompt then that they could accidentally discover, but what’s the problem with that?

Comment: Hey poke, your suggestion works well. I use your code and got the MessageBox.

The things that left is on disabling/preventing/surpress/suspend any combination key that led to program terminate/minimize/switches..

Does I need to access the Low Level API for this?

Comment: I’m not too sure about that. Try setting `e.Handled` to `true` so that the event definitely stops propagating. Other than that, I think you will be able to get some more instructions by searching for “kiosk mode” (which is essentially what you are trying to implement here).