# Leap doesn't seem to update when wpf window isn't active

Tags: wpf, leap-motion

I am trying to use output from the leap in WPF. However whenever I unfocus the window (for instance by pressing alt+tab), the leap stops giving output.
So my question is, how to make sure the leap will output even when focused on a second application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the Leap Motion API [background frames policy](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/api/Leap.Controller.html#csharpclass_leap_1_1_controller_1a2e9e33b47c2b764f92304fc758b8cde4).

```
controller.SetPolicy(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
```

Answer (score -1):

WPF won't listen to any events outside its window. You have to explicitly set it up by yourself to listen to "globally" events.

An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp) of a global event is listening to keyboard even outside WPF's window

Comment: The problem is not related to WPF itself, but Leap Motion settings instead.