# how to set WPF to allways recognize input

Tags: c#, wpf, leap-motion

I am working on an wpf project with leap motion. My programm is allways checking for input via the leap motion controller and does something with it.

But when I open another programm (and my wpf gets in the background) my wpf freezes.

Is there a way my programm will not freeze even if I open another programm in fullscreen ?

EDIT:
here is how i get my input:

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
        InitializeComponent();

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += Update;
 }

 protected void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        //get frame
        Leap.Frame frame = leap.Frame();

        ...
 }
```

Comment: If you don't want this question to get down voted into oblivion, you should consider adding some code showing how you are doing input.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://pulunsurendra.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/create-console-key-logger-using-c.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728839/leap-doesnt-seem-to-update-when-wpf-window-isnt-active/28736170#28736170

Comment: Thank you this solved it for me @Charles Ward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Charles Ward this did it for me:

```
controller.SetPolicy(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
```

[Leap doesn't seem to update when wpf window isn't active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728839/leap-doesnt-seem-to-update-when-wpf-window-isnt-active/28736170#28736170)