# How to bind a hotkey

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

I'm trying to create a program where I can press a hotkey while I'm in a game and the program will receive the key press and preform an action. I've tried following tutorials and looking at other questions, but they seem to not provide the functionality I want or the methods are outdated and I cannot use them without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do this with WINAPI Interop. The technique is usually referred to as a global [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You'll want to handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` , `WM_KEYUP`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, and `WM_SYSKEYUP` events. You can read up on WPF and Win32 specific interoperation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can read up on planform invoke (PInvoke) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  Pinvoke is how you call unmanaged / native functions implemented in a dll from your .NET application.

For example, you can call the `SetWindowsHookEx` [(Pinvoke)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex) | [(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method in the user32.dll to install an application hook.

```
IntPtr hHook;

using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
using (ProcessModule module = process.MainModule)
{
    IntPtr hModule = GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName);

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, hModule, 0);
}
```

You can find Pinvoke signatures at this wiki site: http://www.pinvoke.net

[Here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowshookex) is a minimal keyboard hook example.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639331/using-global-keyboard-hook-wh-keyboard-ll-in-wpf-c-sharp) is an example C# / WPF example that could help you get started.